# Customize Enfold theme on my WP site

Tags: wordpress, header, custom-headers, tenfold

I've to customize the header in Enfold theme of my WP site. I placed the company logo to the left and under this I placed the primary menu. I need to add another image near to the company logo. I 'created' a theme child and I would like to add a widget to place image on the right of the company logo but the theme expected in the header the company logo and the primary menu only. Can I customize my header to do this? Can you help me please? Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

If you have purchased the enfold theme, you will get the child theme along with that. Your header part (menu and logo) is running from helper-main-menu.php file which is located at enfold/includes/helper-main-menu.php

Now to get this in child theme add the header.php to your child theme and then add a folder named includes and keep a copy of helper-main-menu.php. This should be as same as in parent theme.

Now you can edit your child theme files and add as many widgets you need.

I have tested and it worked for me.Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that your theme is from themeforest so you should create a child theme, then copy your header.php in child theme folder. Then make changes on that file.

For creating a child theme, make a folder inside your 'themes' folder with you child theme name. Now the child theme should have a style sheet in it which is a must. So add a style sheet and the beginning of the child theme style sheet should be as follows:

```
/*  
Theme Name: (theme name) Child
Theme URI: (give URL)
Description: (give description)
Version: (give your version)
Author: (author name)
Author URI: (give URL)
Template: (name of parent theme)
*/
```

Of these the very important thing is the 'Template' which is the parent theme name. To avoid confusion take the name of parent theme from the parent theme style sheet.

Now the second thing is the functions of your child theme. Just add a php file with the name functions.php and place the below code.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

This code is for enqueuing the parent theme styles. Here you go! your child theme will work now.

Comment: thank you very much.. I've already done this steps but my problem is that the Enfold theme (so my child theme also) expected in the header the company logo and the primary menu only..I would like add a widget to my header for to place an image on the right of the logo.. Can you help me, please?